# phpMyAdmin Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to join my database in phpadmin but there is an error

xampp :

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:20:26 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

phpadmin : [image: this is image error shown in phpadmin]

i tried to change my port in my.ini and add it on config.inc

but error still coming

Comment: Does it stops whenever you lunch it? or what exactly triggers it?

Comment: Yes whenever i started the mysql.